# How can I combine uniroot and lapp/overlay function from terra package to perform raster calculation?

Tags: r, raster, terra, uniroot

I am trying to lapp from terra package to solve an equation with raster cells and uniroot function. I am stuck on how to get the final raster output from combining lapp and uniroot functions.
I would be thankful for any kind of help

```
library(terra)

Psi_water <- rast("SUB100_120/hb_SUB100_120.tif");
Psi_water <- Psi_water*10*-1
names(Psi_water) <- "Psi_water"
Ksat <- rast("SUB100_120/ksat_SUB100_120.tif");
Ksat <- abs(Ksat*240)
names(Ksat) <- "Ksat"
Lambda <- rast("SUB100_120/lambda_SUB100_120.tif");
names(Lambda) <- "Beta"
theta_r1 <- rast("SUB100_120/theta_r_SUB100_120.tif")
names(theta_r1) <- "theta_r"
theta_s1 <- rast("SUB100_120/theta_s_SUB100_120.tif")
names(theta_s1) <- "theta_s"

#Biophysical parameters
Tp= 6.5         
EC50= 8.8493    
p= 3              
Psi_Root=-6000  
b= 10           
Yr0= 0

#Water Salinity (EC)
EC <- seq(0.5, 6, 1)  

#Irrigation water
I <- seq(0.4 , 12.2, by =3.86)

#function 
fct <- function (Psi_water, Ksat, Lambda, theta_s, theta_r, EC, t, I, b,  Tp, EC50, p, Psi_Root) { 
    Eta <-  2 + 3 * Lambda
    Delta <- Eta / Lambda
    Num_inner1 <- ((I-t)/Ksat)^(1/Eta)
    Num_inner2 <- abs(Psi_water)/Num_inner1
    Num_inner3 <- abs(Psi_Root)-Num_inner2
    Num_inner4 <- Num_inner3*(I-t)*b
    Num <- min(Tp,Num_inner4)
    Denom_inner1 <- ((I-t)/Ks)^(1/Delta)
    Denom_inner2 <- Theta_r+(theta_s-theta_r)*Denom_inner1
    Denom_inner3 <- EC*I*Denom_inner2
    Denom_inner4 <- EC50*(I-t)*theta_s
    Denom <-  1+(Denom_inner3/Denom_inner4)^p
    Num-Denom*t #round(out,3)
}

layers <- sds(Psi_water, Ksat, Lambda, theta_s, theta_r)

t <- lapp(layers, uniroot(fct, interval = c(0001, 100)), fun=fct)
```

My out is the following: Error in f(lower, ...) : argument "I" is missing, with no default.

```
#Example with numeric values
#Biophysical parameters
Tp= 6.5         
EC50= 8.8493    
p= 3              
Psi_Root=-6000  
b= 10           
Yr0= 0

#soil parameters
Ks= 3600
Beta= 0.55
Eta= 2.7
Theta_s= 0.41
Theta_r= 0.06
Psi_Water= -200
Delta=Eta/Beta

#Water Salinity (EC)
EC <- seq(0.5, 6, 1)  

#Irrigation water
I <- seq(0.4 , 12.2, by =3.86) 

#Optimization function
fct <- function (Tp, EC50,p,Psi_Root,Ks,b,Beta,Eta,Theta_s,Theta_r,Psi_Water,Delta,EC, I,t) { 
  Num_inner1 <- ((I-t)/Ks)^(1/Eta)
  Num_inner2 <- abs(Psi_Water)/Num_inner1
  Num_inner3 <- abs(Psi_Root)-Num_inner2
  Num_inner4 <- Num_inner3*(I-t)*b
  Num <- min(Tp,Num_inner4)
  Denom_inner1 <- ((I-t)/Ks)^(1/Delta)
  Denom_inner2 <- Theta_r+(Theta_s-Theta_r)*Denom_inner1
  Denom_inner3 <- EC*I*Denom_inner2
  Denom_inner4 <- EC50*(I-t)*Theta_s
  Denom <-  1+(Denom_inner3/Denom_inner4)^p
  out <- Num-Denom*t#round(out,3)
  return(out)
}
#max guess for upper uniroot level
max_guess=(I-Ks*(Psi_Water/Psi_Root)^Eta);max_guess

t <- matrix(NA, ncol=length(EC), nrow=length(I))
rownames(t) <- I
colnames(t) <- EC

for (j in 1:length(EC)) {
  for (i in 1:length(I)) {
    max_guess[i]
    opt <- uniroot(f=fct, Tp=Tp, EC50=EC50,p=p,Psi_Root=Psi_Root,Ks=Ks,b=b,Beta=Beta,
                   Eta=Eta,Theta_s=Theta_s,Theta_r=Theta_r,Psi_Water=Psi_Water,Delta=Delta,EC=EC[j],I=I[i], interval=c(0.001*Tp, max_guess[i]))
    
    t[i, j] = opt$root 
  }
}
t
#output
> t
             0.5        1.5        2.5        3.5        4.5        5.5
0.4   0.03010785 0.03010785 0.03010785 0.03010785 0.03010785 0.03010785
4.26  3.88991889 3.88990654 3.87785872 3.72455754 3.57576228 3.43192052
8.12  6.49502364 6.38842824 6.14818024 5.85978470 5.56571210 5.27915708
11.98 6.49935915 6.48287826 6.42364157 6.30540640 6.12903770 5.90777669
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your question to make make it reproducible (include some example data, see the terra help files for how to do that) and shorter, if possible? Can you also show how to call your function `fct` with numeric input values?

Comment: @RobertHijmans I add an example of calling the function using numerical values and I also add a link to the example raster data. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question (above) and remove your "answer" (below). Also please provide example data that do not need to be downloaded (that is, either create them with code, or use data that ship with R --- see the examples in the help files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the raster data from your [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GgbV2Jock2Uqf18A_U4b2rJgWQPYbvOw?usp=share_link) I created a self-contained reproducible example data (please include something like that in future questions):

```
r <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10)
n <- ncell(r)
set.seed(232)
Psi_Water <- setValues(r, runif(n, -8, -1))
Ks <- setValues(r, runif(n, .1, 465))
Beta <- setValues(r, runif(n, .22, .41))
theta_r <- setValues(r, runif(n, .03, .14))
theta_s <- setValues(r, runif(n, .4, .53))
x <- c(Psi_Water, Ks, Beta, theta_r, theta_s)
names(x) <- c("Psi_Water", "Ks", "Beta", "Theta_r", "Theta_s")
```

Your function

```
fct <- function(Tp, EC50, p, Theta_s, Theta_r, Psi_Water, Psi_Root, Ks, b, Beta, Eta,  Delta, EC, I, t) { 
    Num_inner1 <- ((I-t)/Ks)^(1/Eta)
    Num_inner2 <- abs(Psi_Water)/Num_inner1
    Num_inner3 <- abs(Psi_Root)-Num_inner2
    Num_inner4 <- Num_inner3*(I-t)*b
    Num <- min(Tp,Num_inner4)
    Denom_inner1 <- ((I-t)/Ks)^(1/Delta)
    Denom_inner2 <- Theta_r+(Theta_s-Theta_r)*Denom_inner1
    Denom_inner3 <- EC*I*Denom_inner2
    Denom_inner4 <- EC50*(I-t)*Theta_s
    Denom <-  1+(Denom_inner3/Denom_inner4)^p
    Num-Denom*t
}
```

Use that function in another function that calls `uniroot`. `uniroot` is not vectorized, so we need to do a loop. It also does not handle `NA` in the search interval, so we need to deal with that as well.

```
unifun <- function(Psi_Water, Ks, Beta, Theta_s, Theta_r, 
    Tp=6.5, EC50=8.8493, p=3, Psi_Root=-6000, Eta= 2.7,  b= 10, Yr0= 0, EC=0.5, I=0.4) {
    n <- length(Psi_Water)
    out <- rep(NA, n)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        max_guess=(I-Ks[i]*(Psi_Water[i]/Psi_Root)^Eta)
        if (is.na(max_guess)) next

        Delta=Eta/Beta[i]

        opt <- uniroot(f=fct, Theta_r=Theta_r[i], Psi_Water=Psi_Water[i], Ks=Ks[i], Theta_s=Theta_s[i], Beta=Beta[i], Tp=Tp, EC50=EC50, p=p, Psi_Root=Psi_Root, b=b, Eta=Eta, Delta=Delta,  EC=EC, I=I, interval=c(0.001*Tp, max_guess))
        out[i] <- opt$root
    }
    out
}
```

Now call the function with `lapp`. You can change default parameter settings.

```
lapp(x, unifun, usenames=TRUE, I=2.5, EC=8.12)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :     lyr1 
#min value   : 1.203867 
#max value   : 1.704232
```

Note that, as we are using `usenames=TRUE`, the variable (layer) names *exactly* match the argument names in the function.

Comment: When using the code with the files from the drive, it gives an error because of the NA value (Error in uniroot(f = fct, Theta_r = Theta_r[i], Psi_Water = Psi_Water[i], : 
f.upper = f(upper) is NA). Seems that "is.na" does not work in this case.

Comment: I am not sure why, but it looks like that fails with the CRAN version, but not with the dev version of terra. You can install the dev version with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks a lot!